# talkback reads capital letters as a word, it should read separate

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

like "US" it is a acronym of United States.
android talkback reads it as a word like "us" but it should read separate like U S.

Please help, is there any other speech voices that read it separately or any other settings in accessibility. please suggest.

Comment: I have a similar issue. In my app, I set text eg. "YUIEU" or "ASDDF" etc - on a TextView field which don't mean anything but a chat room code that users can join. How do I set right contentDescription for this ? That room code is randomly generated so I dont have control over which string to read.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior your point out is necessary.  Android uses all capital letters for some standard controls.  For example, TabWidgets.  All the letters in a TabWidget will be capitalized automatically.  Would you want the tabs "TAB1", "TAB2"... to read out 'T A B 1'... of course not.  There is however, a solution, for your circumstance.

You can provide a content description for items that have text.  The content description will override the text when available.  I would recommend the following.

Text: The USA is cool!

Content Description: The U S A is cool!

Recommended ContDesc: The United States of America is cool! (Do the acronym expansion for them, TalkBack actually reads this faster than U S A!)

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding period after U as U.S or add an aria-label attribute as aria-label="U.S"/aria-label="United States"

Answer (score 0):

Adding period after each capital letter helps talkback feature to read it as Abbreviations, with all capital letters separated out. I used android:text="US" to display without bullets, but added android:contentDescription="U.S." so that talkback read it separately.